# Mouse Click with C++

Tags: c++, windows-7, click, mouse, mouseevent

Is there anyway to force a mouse click using C++ outside of my application? For example, if a mouse is in a certain coordinate, it is forced to click.

Comment: Within your own application, or any on the system?

Comment: For that, you probably want to write a mouse driver-esque thing.

Comment: Some sort of driver that tells the system that the mouse has clicked somewhere (even if it hasn't). For that, you need to write a driver. Bit of overkill, eh? I'm sure there is a better solution, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @Linuxios I don't want to know if the mouse has clicked somewhere, I want to make it click somewhere

Comment: I understand that. If you made a pretend driver, it could send mouse click events to the system without there actually being a mouse click. Great opportunity for malware, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
HWND h = (hwnd of window)
WORD mouseX = 10;// x coord of mouse
WORD mouseY = 10;// y coord of mouse
PostMessage(hWnd,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,0,MAKELPARAM(mouseX,mouseY));
```

Taken from [this site](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/200043-simulate-mouse-click-to-non-foreground-window-using-sendmessage/).

Answer (score 1):

this should do fine:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/17053/